# Altering partitions of hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.  I need more disk space and my current configuration is as follows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/loop0       17G   17G  6.1M 100% /

udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev

tmpfs           773M  860K  772M   1% /run

none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock

none            1.9G  364K  1.9G   1% /run/shm

/dev/sda3       284G  108G  176G  38% /host

overflow        1.0M   40K  984K   4% /tmp
```

The size of the Windows partition `/dev/sda3` is way more than I need.  I'd like to free up about 100-125 GB and move it to the Ubuntu partition `/dev/loop0`.  I expect to be working with databases around 25 GB in size and want to have room to grow.

Are the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk the most appropriate ones to use?

Is there a compelling reason for me to consider using a different form of Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Gparted to accomplish your task.

> This article shows how you can modify the partitioning of your Linux
>   system with GParted (Gnome Partition Editor) without losing data. This
>   includes resizing partitions (enlarging and shrinking), moving
>   partitions on the hard drive, creating and deleting partitions, and
>   even modifying filesystem types. GParted is a free partition editor
>   available as a desktop program and also as a Live-CD. It supports the
>   following filesystems: ext2, ext3, fat16, fat32, hfs, hfs+, jfs,
>   linux-swap, reiserfs, reiser4, ufs, xfs, and even ntfs (Windows).
>   [Have alook at this](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted)

<sup>Source: [howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted)</sup>

If you don't have Gparted instaaled, you can install it

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Or

[image]